# Crash accesing a string inside pointer stored in vector

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector, wstring

I cannot imagine a single reason for this... here is my base class

```
class TextureElement
{
public:
    TextureElement(std::wstring mname);
    std::wstring file;
    std::wstring name;
    TexMode texmode;
};
```

And this is a basic usage:

```
TextureElement* textureElement = new TextureElement(prename);
mClass->textures.push_back(textureElement);
textureElement->file = path;//<<here crashes if inheritance is done
```

obviously prename and path are wstrings, mstruct mClass contains several vectors including this one that stores TextureElement* type

This works ok but if I inherit TextureElement from Element

```
class Element
{
public:
    Element(std::wstring mname, ElementType t);
    Element(){};
    ~Element();
    ElementType type;
    std::wstring name;
};
```

It crashes.

I've tried implementing copy method for TextureElement (I was almost sure it was unnecessary) but it didn't worked.
Any idea on this? Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `path`? `wchar_t*` I guess? What if `path==nullptr`?

Comment: Heap corruption also might take place. If the heap is corrupted, any memory allocation might lead to crash.

Comment: First give TextureElement a virtual destructor. Second, `Element` doesn't actually inherit from `TextureElement` in your code.

Comment: path was a wstring

@AndyG yes probably I didn't explain it properly, the code there is not crashing since it doesn't inherits, but if I add that inheritance it crash.

Comment: @FrankEscobar: What is the definition of  `mClass->textures`? What do you store in the `vector`? The crash on the string assignment might be a consequence of some bad coding practice elsewhere.

Comment: @ivaigult path is a std::wstring, where do you think it could be a heap issue?

Comment: I'm curious what happens if you assign path before inserting into vector.

Comment: @FrankEscobar: The `name` member in `Element` would hide `TextureElement`'s `name` member. Make sure you remove that. Also, show your constructor for `Element`, I hope you're calling the base class' and passing in `mname`

Comment: Please show the declaration for the vector as well... I smell slicing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are inheriting from `Element`, you may want to declare a **`virtual` destructor** for proper cleanup:

```
virtual ~Element() {}
```

Moreover, pay attention when you put *raw owning pointers* in `std::vector`. Consider a vector of *smart* pointers, like `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` or `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` instead.

---

**EDIT**

This code compiles just fine and seems to work (tested on VS2015 with Update 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum class ElementType
{
    Texture,
    Foo,
    Bar
};

class Element
{
public:
    Element(const wstring& name, ElementType type) 
        : Name(name), Type(type)
    {}

    virtual ~Element() {}

    ElementType Type;
    wstring Name;
};

class TextureElement : public Element
{
public:
    explicit TextureElement(const wstring &name)
        : Element(name, ElementType::Texture)
    {}

    wstring File;
};

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Element>> v;

    auto p = make_shared<TextureElement>(L"Test");
    v.push_back(p);
    p->File = L"C:\\Some\\File";

    wcout << p->File;
}
```

Comment: What advantage could I get from using shared_ptr on this case?
btw yes probably I should add the destructor but I think that this won't fix the crash

Comment: @FrankEscobar: The bottom line is that a vector of raw owning pointers is a bug factory and a source of "leaktrocities". Raw _observing_ pointers are fine.

Comment: I've tried with shared_ptr but it crashes again

Comment: Do you allocate the item with make_shared? And what happens if you assign path before push_back-ing into vector?

Comment: I added a sample compilable code.